# Android permission to take photo only from gallery

Tags: android, android-permissions

In this link he mentioned the situtation that there is no need to write a permission in Manifest.xml to take photos from your gallery.
He wrote it in: 3/01/12

http://gizmodo.com/5889742/android-apps-can-also-steal-your-photo-library

Is this situation still the same? Can an app that I downloaded from Google Play Store steal my photos without any permission?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is more from a user than from a developer but anyway. There are some tricks to put barrers to the apps which try to access to your sensitive information.

Try with this solution (this article's been pubhished in 2013).

[Link](http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-stop-Android-apps-from-accessing-your-sensitive-private-data-hint-revoke-permissions_id50744)

Comment: I've read that article.But if I was a person that tried to download an app from Android Market in 2012 there would be no notificiation about application's reach capability to my photos in gallery.And that application would be capable of stealing them without my knowledge.Is this situation still the same? Or Google added some notification to let the user know about "application's permission to read photos from library" ? You know, there appears a pop-up dialog box when you try to download something.In 2012 there was no permission to read photos but app was able to read photos. In 2014?

Answer (score 0):

How do you think that app can steal photos?

1. It is not using any permission.

In that case, even if it accesses the gallery and stores the images in a dynamic database, it still won't be able to transfer the images to wherever it puts stolen content to. [ Doesn't use Internet. ]

1. If it is using Internet..
   Most apps use it. That's why everyone has got to be careful.

Comment: In the link that I gave above, he says "there is no need to a permission for an Android application to read photos or pictures in your phone ". But that post was in 2012.So is there a change about this situation since is what I was trying to ask.

Comment: The application has to use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: https://github.com/itcuties/Android-Pick-Image-from-Gallery/blob/master/ITCPickGalleryImageApp/AndroidManifest.xml   
There is no permission in this sample project?

Comment: I saw.Thank you.But what does it mean? I downloaded an app to my Android phone whose API level is under 19.If it had an action that tries to get photo from my gallery, would I see it as a permission when I try to download it from Google Play Store? Or without "permission notification" of READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", does it work on my phone and can gets photos? @AbhishekSoni

Comment: I'll get back to you after checking it.. or you can tell me by running it on your device.. and see if it can access your gallery or not?

Comment: Yes I'm going to try it now.And if you can write me the result, too,  that will be great

Comment: I will post soon about it.

Comment: I figured it out at least.Any app can reach phone's photo gallery without any permission.So it hasn't changed. @AbhishekSoni